# Eclipse: Find references in Java and JSF/JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jsf

I have lot of legacy models in MVC application and there are lot of redundant properties in model classes.

Using **CTRL + SHIFT + G** in Eclipse I can find references in Java code, but not in my views, which are mostly JSP or JSF pages. Therefore, I cannot safely refactor code.

The only option then is plain String search which is not  comfortable and more error prone. Is there solution?

Comment: I don't think eclipse has that capability. Netbeans has that.

Comment: Are you sure you have the full J(2)EE environment installed in your Eclipse instance? You need the proper JSP editor..

Comment: Well I have Eclipse for Java EE development so I guess so. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JBoss Tools 3.3 plugin](http://jboss.org/tools) has this capability (and many more, such as tag and EL autocompletion). Note that it's currently still in development (beta) stage. You can get it in Eclipse Indigo (3.7.x) by *Help > Install New Software* and then entering the URL of [this update site](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/). In the list of available plugins components, just pick the "JBoss Web and Java EE Development" option (others are not required). No, this does not require a JBoss AS server as your project's target runtime.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I have @ManagedBean called "NumberGenerator" with "number" property (get,set) and it is used in JSF2 page like this: <h:outputText value="#{numberGenerator.number}". When I navigate to getNumber() getter and press CTRL+SHIFT+G (find references), none are found even though "number" property is used in EL expression.

Can you post picture if it works for you or write little more about that? Thanks

Comment: Okay I don't know what was wrong, I restared computer and it does work as expected. Thanks BalusC!

Comment: I added a screenshot as evidence.

Comment: Will this work if the search is performed in a .jsp file? It already works in a .java file without this plugin inside Eclipse, which is what your screenshot is showing so I'm confused.